# Rename [oci] to [oracle-call-interface] and create new [oci] tag, merging it with [oracle-cloud-infrastructure]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

*Note: Updated text following discussions/ suggestions*

I would like to ask to rename [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) tag to `oracle-call-interface` and then re-create [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) tag, merging the new tag with [oracle-cloud-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-cloud-infrastructure).

The current situation is:

- [OCI - Oracle Cloud Infrastructure](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/) is the name/ short for the new Oracle cloud, we expect the use of the tag to increase overtime and possibly span other subtags with other cloud services (example, I believe that in the future we will see tags like `oci-compute`, `oci-adw` and so forth, similarly to how aws and azure grew organically)
- Currently [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) tag is mapped to *Oracle Call Interface* - an (Oracle) API to allow apps to access Oracle DB, however looking at the questions that use [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) tag, we see that while a portion of the questions refer to the use of the API, many others meant to refer *Oracle Cloud Infrastructure* (the fact that some are asking questions about querying Oracle database is not the only indicator - as many Database services are now in OCI - like DBaaS and ADW)
- [oracle-cloud-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-cloud-infrastructure) usage is still small but will likely keep increasing in the next couple of months with the growth of the platform and migration of new services from Oracle's *old cloud* (now named OCI-classic) to the new/modern Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI).
- Oleg's [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1263219?tag=oci-) below (using `oci-` as input) shows that some of these Oracle Cloud Infrastructure subtags already started to surface - for example [oci-java-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci-java-sdk), [oci-python-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci-python-sdk), and [oci-typescript-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci-typescript-sdk)

In summary is my updated proposal after discussions:

1. 'Rename' [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) to [oracle-call-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-call-interface) - that would result on moving all questions to the new name (Overtime the community would be able to clean-up the questions that do not apply to the API).
2. Create a brand new `oci` tag, merge it with [oracle-cloud-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-cloud-infrastructure) (tags would be synonymous) - being [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) as the main tag as short for *Oracle Cloud Infrastructure*, and  the secondary being the current [oracle-cloud-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-cloud-infrastructure) - this change/ merge would contribute to better be prepared for the future growth of oci as a cloud brand, allowing it to spin off to other subtags as more and more Oracle products onboard to the new cloud and the platform grows in popularity.

Answer (score 3):

> Currently [oci] tag is mapped to *Oracle Call Interface* - an (Oracle) API to allow apps to access Oracle DB, however looking at the questions that use [[oci]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci?sort=newest) tag, we see that the majority of the questions refer not to the use of the API, but to use of Oracle Cloud Infrastructure itself

This isn't true.  I scanned the first page of results in that link, and 40 of the 50 results seem to be about querying/interacting with Oracle databases, most specifically mentioning OCI libraries. It's possible someone has removed a lot of the inaccurately tagged questions, but I'm skeptical that's the case, as the ones about Oracle Cloud Infrastructure were sprinkled somewhat randomly through the list.

Even if that were the case, though, the solution wouldn't be to merge the tags, because this would leave a large number of mistagged questions.  Instead, the incorrectly tagged questions need to have their tags fixed.

In addition to that, it might make sense to rename the current [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) tag to something less error-prone, perhaps [oracle-call-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-call-interface).  But we shouldn't do that by merging its current state with another tag and then recreating it, as we'd lose valuable question tagging information.

Comment: Yeah I like your suggestion - you are right that some portion of the questions refer to Oracle Call Interface and some others Oracle Cloud Infrastructure - the fact that is querying an Oracle DB is not a determinant factor as DBaaS and ADW also runs in Oracle OCI cloud --- but the reality is that currently this is confusing for users -- and you are right that just merging would lose some context -- perhaps renaming oci to oracle-call-interface - and then creating oci, and setting oracle-cloud-infrastructure as synonymous may be a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Given the current naming convention (see [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1263219?tag=oracle-)) for the `oracle-*` prefixed tags it may be advisable to simply rename [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) to [oracle-call-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-call-interface) like both the question (partially) and Ryan's answer propose and do nothing else.

That said, one should also take into account that `oci-*` prefixed tags [refer to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=oci-) and have wiki excerpts (first 2 tags do not have any excerpts) referencing it. They should either be rewritten or disambiguated if the [oci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci) si to be changed to [oracle-call-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-call-interface):

[oci-go-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci-go-sdk) [oci-typescript-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci-typescript-sdk)

[oci-java-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci-java-sdk)
Oracle Cloud infrastructure is an infrastructure cloud computing service offered by Oracle Corporation. By using Java SDK you can install, configure Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. Use this tag for questions referring to the oci or Java platform sdk.

[oci-python-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oci-python-sdk)
The Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Python SDK is a python package that provides an interface to the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI). Use this tag for questions related to using the Python SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the query. I like Ryan's approach, and I would go further to say that I expect that the number of `oci-*` prefixed tags will grow as more Oracle products move to OCI. So I would recommend also re-creating `oci` after rename to [oracle-call-interface]

Comment: @AndreTeixeira - thank you for providing responses to both answers  - glad you found the info useful. You should probaly include that info in your proposal, so those who will make the decision about the rename will be better informed and spend less time researching for themselves.